# How can I increase session lifetime in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session-timeout, symfony-2.4

I have set the gc_maxlifetime in my config.yml file to 300. But its not working. Symfony2 still takes the value set in php.ini

Symfony version is 2.4.4

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the **cookie_lifetime** parameters of the session config key.

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 300 # override php.ini config
```

as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime)

hope this help

Comment: I have set gc_maxlifetime: 300 and cookie_lifetime: 300 in Symfony config.yml. In php.ini I have set the gc_maxlifetime to 60. Setting the cookie_lifetime also didn't work as the user is still logged out after 60 seconds

Comment: very strange, check if you are verify the correct php.ini (apache instead of the cli) watching directly the sf2 profile page as follow example: http://localhost/app_dev.php/_profiler/phpinfo

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach (gotten from Drupal configuration):

1. set handler to `native_file` (i'd use PDOSessionHanlder, but seems it's not very stable);
2. create a `seesions` directory under `app` folder;

`config.yml` file:

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    cookie_domain: %cookie_domain%
    name: SFSESSID
    cookie_lifetime: 2000000 # change this if you want
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
    gc_divisor: 100
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000 # change this if you want
    gc_probability: 1
```